# Ubuntu 18.04 login loop after installing flatpak

Tags: login, gimp, flatpak

Recently, I saw a new way to install the latest version of gimp is using an terminal application named flatpak, installed it, been able to start and use the gimp to the point that i decided to restart my computer. After that, doestn't matter how many times i try to enter my password, it drops me back to same screen over and over again. I solve the issue with deleting flatpak from virtual console, but that means launching gimp is not possible anymore.

Since apt not gives me the latest version, and I want to understand what is the issue about flatpak and if it is broken somehow, how should I solve the issue or install gimp with another way?

Comment: Flatpak or snap versions are not so well integrated with the rest. If you use Ubuntu 18+ you can get the latest and greatest Gimp as a standard application from the [Gimp PPA](https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp). It also has packages for popular Gimp plugins that you may not find in the snap or flatpak versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. In my case the problem was that the `flatpak` directory in the `/home/test/.local/share` directory was owned by `root:root`. I fixed this as follows:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.
2. Then log in.
3. Fix directory owner.

   ```
   sudo chown -R test:test /home/test/.local/share/flatpak
   ```
4. You can go back to the GUI by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.
5. Login works.

Answer (score 1):

First: get ride of the login loop.
Second: installing gimp using snap.

Simply, You can get ride of the log in loop by uninstall what you just have installed.

1. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Then log in
3. Uninstall flatpack with `sudo apt-get purge flatpak`
4. You can go back to GUI by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Hope you can login now, then you can install gimp using snap:
if you don't have snap install it using `sudo apt-get install snap`
then install gimp with `sudo snap install gimp`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I already purged and managed to login actually, but gimp is also gone with the flatpak, although snap is probably going to work.

Comment: You're welcome.